# Set MySQL server variable collation_connection to utf8_unicode_ci on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, utf-8, collation, amazon-rds

So my goal is to set all the character sets and collations to `utf8` and `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Im using an AWS RDS to host the MySQL server.

Ive set the `collation_connection variable` to `utf8_unicode_ci` in the Parameter group for the RDS.
[image: This is how I set the variable in the parameter group]
.

Ive then rebooted my RDS and when going to MySQL console it shows the following values for variables.

```
mysql> show variables like "%character%";show variables like "%collation%";
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                     |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                      |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                      |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                      |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                      |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                      |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.22.R1/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

Im not sure why the `collation_connection` is set as `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Changing the table to general does fix the problem i was having (in regards to my update not working - http://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in/2014/07/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8-general-ci-implicit.html but still i dont know why collation_connection isnt changing.

Comment: Did you end up fixing this issue? As I am also facing the same with Amazon RDS parameter group.

Comment: nope, still interested in a potential solution

Comment: I have this same issue too and would be interested in a solution

Comment: I wrote an answer with a solution to this. I guess this problem will be seen more frequently nowadays, since MySQL 8.0 has changed the default utf8mb4 collation.

Answer (score 7):

The variables which you see here are the current client session's variables:

```
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

So, you need to run the following commands, when you initiate the connection, on the client from which you are connecting:

```
SET collation_connection = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

Answer (score 4):

The `collation_connection` variable is set by the client; clients may be compiled with different settings - in this case, the default collation for `utf8` appears to be `utf8_general_ci`.

The problem is that the MySQL client allows the user to set the charset (`default-character-set`), but not the collation. If one needs a specific collation, this can't be directly worked around.

In this case, what one can do (besides runtime changes) is to set the server `character-set-client-handshake` variable off (`0`).
This will skip the character set (and implicitly, collation) negotiation with the client(s), and will impose the server charset/collation settings on any client connection.

Comment: Encountered the same issue, this is the correct answer. Solves the problem exactly.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Solves the problem exactly. 

Answer (score 1):

In the Parameter group, set the variable **init_connect** to

> SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: This has already been covered in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40900613/2605758).

Answer (score 0):

I did it - prescribed in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`

```
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
```

I don’t know/don’t understand how identical the two parameters (--skip... and FALSE), but if they are identical, then in the official documentation it says

> Don't ignore client side character set value sent during handshake. (Defaults to on; use --skip-character-set-client-handshake
> to disable.)

Also in the documentation, I did not find anything about the value **FALSE**, but it works.

Answer (score -5):

If you have any existing tables with different `CHARACTER SET` or `COLLATION`, they need converting; see `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...`.

If you code does not connect as `utf8`, that needs changing.  The details are very language specific (Java vs PHP vs ...).

And, if you are doing html pages, they need to start with

```
<meta charset=UTF-8>
```

As long as you are going through this exercise, you should go all the way, so that you can handle all of Chinese and Emoji:  `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

Comment: Thx, but do you know why the collation_connection is still set as utf8_general_ci? (even after I set collation_connection variable to utf8_unicode_ci in the Parameter group).

Comment: Sorry, I am unfamiliar with "parameter group"; I don't even know what product has that.  <opinion>There are too many 3rd party packages adding too little value to MySQL</opinion>