# Why is MySQL Workbench showing wrong collation in table editor?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, collation

I'm currently using MySQL Workbench 8.0.21. If I press the wrench icon for the table editor window I always get the same (wrong) collation ***utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci***. But this is not the real collation for the table!

[image: default collation is always utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci]

I believe that this must be a bug with the Workbench, because I tried different things:

- Setting the *collation_connection* for the client manually but without effect

  `SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;`
  `SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_general_ci;`
- Checking the [table collation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52479645/426227)

  `SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COLLATION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'parts';`
  which correctly prints *utf8mb8_general_ci*
- Tried to edit *mysql.cnf*

but again without effect:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
#init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;'
init-connect='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_general_ci;'
character-set-server=utf8mb4
```

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683880/change-default-character-set-on-mysql-workbench) seems to be no solution for changing the default character set/collation when connecting with MySQL Workbench.

The setting [*default_collation_for_utf8mb4*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_collation_for_utf8mb4) seems to be only valid for replication purposes. Would be turning off [*character-set-client-handshake*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56547180/426227) an alternative solution for my problem?

Have you also experienced this weird behavior in the Workbench?

Comment: I've given up using MySQL Workbench because it's so buggy. I suggest you do not use dropdowns in the UI as an accurate description of the table's options. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Just uninstall MySQL Workbench and save some disk space. Instead, I use the command-line `mysql` client.

Comment: Keep in mind that StackOverflow is a page for programming-related issues. If you are facing any problem with MySQL Workbench, use superuser.com or DBA

Comment: @NicoHaase: Thanks for your input! The thing is I don't know if it is a Workbench problem or if I have a wrong setting/setup. My first thought was that it is a setting issue, because it seems that nobody else does have this kind of problem ...

Answer (score 1):

`CHARACTER SET` refers to the bits representing the characters.  It is important for sending (`INSERT`, `SELECT`) data between client (Workbench, in your case) and the server (`mysqld`).  It is also specified for each *column* of each table.

`COLLATION` is important only when comparing (`WHERE`) and sorting (`ORDER BY`).  Collation rarely has impact anywhere else.

The default collation for `utf8mb4` is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` for MySQL 8.0.

You need to be concerned about the `CHARACTER SET`, otherwise characters sent between the client and server will likely be mangled.

You *usually* don't need to worry about the `COLLATION`.

`SET NAMES` and `character_set_connection` control the Insert/Select transliteration by specifying the encoding in the *client*.  (It sounds like you are working entirely with `UTF-8`, so no conversion is needed.)

Is the "wrong collation" causing trouble somewhere?  If so, please specify.

You mentioned "replication"; is the Replica having some kind of trouble?

**More**

In the underlying MySQL, when ALTERing a column, you *must* re-specify everything ([NOT] NULL, charset, collation, etc).  Apparently, Workbench fails to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response :-) The wrong displayed collation is irritating when using the Workbench ... One issue I had (but this isn't really related to this question) is: if you generate an update statement where a column should be changed in size (e.g. for VARCHAR) , then the Workbench misses the collation in the statement. As a result the default collation is used, which was wrong in my case. No problem currently detected with replication. Back to the question: why is Workbench showing the wrong collation even if it is explicitely set in the client connection? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @testing - I added more.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One thing I still don't get is why the Workbench shows me the wrong collation despite the `DDL` is correctly displayed as well as `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.